# What should i do to parse Google Maps link to location coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, parsing, location, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Copied the Google Maps link in search results on my iPhone and it looks like:

https://maps.google.com.tw/maps?hl=zh-tw&client=safari&yv=2&um=1&ie=UTF-8&fb=1&gl=tw&entry=s&sa=X&ftid=0x89c259594d6968cd:0x122305eef8f02a47&gmm=CgIgAQ%3D%3D

When I open the link in browser, it will finally been redirected to the link below:

https://www.google.com.tw/maps/place/Best+Pizza/@40.7155798,-73.955601,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c259594d6968cd:0x122305eef8f02a47?hl=zh-tw

Which contains the location coordinates that I'm looking for.

BUT, what should i do to find the location coordinates from this link without sending it via browser?

I think the "ftid" is the parameter that is used to find location in map. But i can't find anything related to the "ftid".

Comment: longitude and langitude

Comment: @FiidoFirdauz hi, thanks for commenting, what does that imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having the same issue, heres what I am going to do with the link you have provided (share link from google maps)

https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+address+seperated+with+plus/@9.419263,99.957389,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3054f4c49057b05d:0xb45d09053b0298d4!8m2!3d9.419263!4d99.959583

Using php I am converting that string into an array

```
$pts = explode('/',$string);
```

That gives me:

```
[0] => https:
    [1] => 
    [2] => www.google.com
    [3] => maps
    [4] => place
    [5] => 4170,+Tambon+Taling+Ngam,+Amphoe+Ko+Samui,+Chang+Wat+Surat+Thani+84140,+Thailand
    [6] => @9.419263,99.957389,17z
    [7] => data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3054f4c49057b05d:0xb45d09053b0298d4!8m2!3d9.419263!4d99.959583
```

I only need key 6, that will always be the same, you always have 0 - 5

next I do the same with its[6]

```
$cords = explode(',',$pts[6]);
```

that gives me"

```
[0] => @9.419263
[1] => 99.957389
[2] => 17z
I use this to store the lon / lat
$lon = str_replace('@','',$cords[0]);
$lat = $cords[1];
```

Hope that helps, it is working for me!